# when using datepicker in android 4.0 and above..how to avoid the calender view

Tags: android, android-datepicker

i have done a project in android 2.2 which contains a date picker and set the properties for it according to he size of screen but when i installed it in android 4.0...the date picker view includes a calender view ....what to do to avoid the calender view along with datepicker in android 4.0...below are the images of date picker in 2.2 and 4.1

[image: android 2.2 image of date picker]

[image: android 4.1 image of date picker]

Comment: you can use the custom date pickers. It will show same view in all versions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8411800/1412308

Comment: can i have an example code please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `yourDatepicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);`

This method works in `Api >= 11` .

Comment: ya i saw this command...but couldn't get this to work as i built my project in 2.2...this command is not working

Comment: @aravindvarma you have to develop project in android 4.0 and set to minimum sdk version to 8

Comment: thanks is there any other way to do so by building in android 2.2

Comment: and as my project is completely done in 2.2 .can i change it to 4.0 or i should write the code again

Comment: @aravindvarma no need to write code again . just change to android 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Use the code of Raval. But to run it below Android version 11, do following:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
          try {
            Method m = datePicker.getClass().getMethod("setCalendarViewShown", boolean.class);
            m.invoke(datePicker, false);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {} // eat exception in our case
        }
```

Now you have it working on all Android versions (Above API > 3)

Comment: i figured  it out...thnks for the reply nyway

Comment: I have a problem :) The code above works fine down to API 8. But on API 4 it crashes. The problem is the setCalendarViewShown() call, although it is not called due to the if-statement. Somehow it is parsed at startup and the app crashes.

Comment: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.DatePicker#setCalendarViewShown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interestingly enclosing the body of the if statement above results in the error I received. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

In Case that you have instance of DatePicker you must write only this in your method `

```
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
            yourDatePickerInstance.setCalendarViewShown(false);
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the Calendar in your DatePicker for later APIs

Add

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

instead of

```
android:calenderViewShown="false"
```

in your layout XML for the DatePicker widget.